# How to run Xserver with VESA driver on top using 24bpp

Tags: xorg, vnc

I am trying to trigger a bug, and to do that I need to run Xserver with VESA driver on top using 24bpp.

I have qemu VMs with all sorts of distors (Ubuntu, CentOS, Debian, OpenSUSE), so please feel free to answer my question in whatever fits you best.

So far, no luck... I trying to connect with VNCViewer:

From the server:

```
# vncserver :1
xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist

Creating default startup script /root/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/vncserver:1.log

CConn:       connected to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 5901
 CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 3.8
 CConnection: Choosing security type VncAuth(2)
```

From the Client:

```
vncviewer hostname:1
```

Then, a window opens and I automatically get logged into gnome-session.
At the same time, in the client terminal, I see:

```
Fri Jan  9 18:56:39 2015
 CConn:       Using pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
 CConn:       Using Tight encoding
 CConn:       Enabling continuous updates

Fri Jan  9 18:56:49 2015
 CConn:       Throughput 2122 kbit/s - changing to quality 6
 CConn:       Using Tight encoding
```

So, as you can see it says: `Using pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888` which is not what I want. I want `24bpp`

Also, I would like to know how can I change the VGA driver and load `vesa`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a `Screen` section in your `xorg.conf` file.  If no `xorg.conf` file exists the server tries to guess the best rate, which in this case is 32 bpp, which is also the Max for most Graphics Adapters.  I found this Example in the [Linear Addressing Section of the Information for Tseng Chipset Users Guide](http://www.xfree86.org/3.3.6/tseng14.html) (Even though the document says XFree86, the same applies to XOrg).

```
Section "screen"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 8
        Virtual 1280 1024
        ViewPort 0 0
        Modes "640x480" "800x600" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 16
        Virtual 1024 992
        ViewPort 0 0
        Modes "640x480" "800x600" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Virtual 960 720
        ViewPort 0 0
        Modes "640x480" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 32
        Virtual 832 600
        ViewPort 0 0
        Modes "640x480" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Notice the Depth Setting.  When Combined with the Modes Setting, you can manually set the resolution and Color Depth.  See also [the xorg.conf(5x) manual page](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.2/doc/xorg.conf.5.html).

Comment: Also, qemu doesn't use vesa

lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Cirrus Logic GD 5446 [1013:00b8] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])


Do you know how to install VESA ?