# How to enable Vesa driver in qemu

Tags: xorg, drivers, qemu

I am running Red Hat 7 into a VM using virt-manager (qemu) and it seems that it uses by default, **Cirrus** driver:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Cirrus Logic GD 5446 [1013:00b8] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: XenSource, Inc. Device [5853:0001]
    Physical Slot: 2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Memory at f3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
```

I would like to know, how can I replace it with VESA. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Xserver with VESA driver on top using 24bpp](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178379/how-to-run-xserver-with-vesa-driver-on-top-using-24bpp).  We told you in this post that Qemu doesn't support VESA, and I showed you how to control the color depth.  Posting the same question here doesn't change the answer :)

Comment: I am talking about depth, but about fbbpp. Also the comment about Vesa it's mine (check the username). Argh, I hate X server, so many configuration files, why they don't have one file...!

Comment: The screen section goes in `xorg.conf`, which is the one file.  I apologize for not recognizing the comment.  Because you are using a VM, you must tailor the "fake" device behavior before stacking on the frame buffer.  When ready add `fbdev` or `fbcon` in the device section.  You need to override the automatic generation by creating a `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but no luck so far.

I also tried passing the `depth 16` as a parameter, and I noticed that the vncserver ignores it. Somehow, it always uses depth 24 and 32bpp. I don't know how to change it.

If it helps: the vncserver uses a ~/.vnc/xstartup file. In this file it says that it launches `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`. Does this help?